# Assembly and C how to compile with GCC-TDM(win10x64) properly?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, nasm, osdev

I am trying to make a simple program. I use windows10x64, qemu(x86_64), C and assembly-nasm. I do not have experience with asm. I am trying to understand it. I use a simple boot.asm, kernel_entry.asm and loader.c files. I based on a totorial.

**boot.asm**

```
;; memory offset where our kernel is located
KERNEL_OFFSET equ 0x1000

;; save the boot drive number
mov [BOOT_DRIVE], dl

;; update base and stack pointers
mov bp, 0x9000
mov sp, bp


init: 
  mov si, msg ; loads the address of "msg" into SI register 
  mov ah, 0x0e ; sets AH to 0xe (function teletype) 
print_char: 
  lodsb ; loads the current byte from SI into AL and increments the address in SI 
  cmp al, 0 ; compares AL to zero 
  je done ; if AL == 0, jump to "done" 
  int 0x10 ; print to screen using function 0xe of interrupt 0x10
  jmp print_char ; repeat with next byte

;; call routine that loads kernel into memory
call load_kernel_into_memory

;; switch to Protected Mode
call switch_to_pm
jmp $

;; routine reads kernel from disk into memory
load_kernel_into_memory:
    ;; store all register values
    pusha
    ;; set up parameters for disk_read routine
    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET
    mov dh, 15
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    call disk_read

    ;; restore register values and ret
    popa
    ret
;

[bits 32]

begin_pm:
    ;; Check if we can move from Protected Mode to Long Mode
    ;; If something went wrong (detect_lm shouldnt return at all)
    ;; we call execute_kernel in x32 Protected Mode
    call detect_lm
    call execute_kernel
    jmp $

[bits 64]

begin_lm:
    ;; In case, if detect_lm and switch_to_lm works fine, call kernel in x64 mode
    call execute_kernel
    jmp $
;
execute_kernel:
    call KERNEL_OFFSET
    jmp $
;
%include "disk/disk_read.asm";
%include "lm/detect_lm.asm";
%include "lm/switch_to_lm.asm";
%include "pm/gdt.asm"
%include "pm/switch_to_pm.asm"
%include "print/print_string.asm";
%include "print/print_nl.asm";


BOOT_DRIVE: db 0

done: 
  hlt ; stop execution 
  msg: db "PROGRAM STARTED", 0x0a; we need to explicitely put the zero byte here 
;

times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; fill the output file with zeroes until 510 bytes are full 
dw 0xaa55 ; magic number that tells the BIOS this is bootable
```

**kernel_entry.asm**

```
global _start
global kernel_main

[bits 32]
[extern _kernel_main] ; I use "_" otherwise it will not compile. _kernel_main comes from "c" file.
                      ;In there that is kernel_main

_start:
  call _kernel_main
  jmp $
```

**loader.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void kernel_main() {
//printf("test");
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        char c = 0x41 + i;

        asm(
            "mov %0, %%al;"
            "mov $0x0E, %%ah;"
            "int $0x10;"
            :
            : "r" (c)
        );
    }
}
```

I COMPILE ON WINx64 with nasm-WINx64version and GCC-TDM.

MY STEPS ARE:

```
nasm kernel_entry.asm -f elf32 -o loader_entry.o

gcc -O0 -g -ffreestanding -m32 -c C:/Users/_USR_/Desktop/nasm-2.15.05/loader.c -o C:/Users/_USR_/Desktop/nasm-2.15.05/loader.o

ld -o "C:/Users/_USR_/Desktop/nasm-2.15.05/loader.tmp" -m i386pe -Ttext 0x1000 -T NUL C:/Users/_USR_/Desktop/nasm-2.15.05/loader_entry.o C:/Users/_USR_/Desktop/nasm-2.15.05/loader.o

objcopy -O binary loader.tmp loader.bin

type boot.bin loader.bin > myboot.bin
```

In the end I run it in QEMU and get "program started" output but not "C" language message. Additionally, I get undeclared error when I use *printf("...");*. One more thing if I add *-lc* param in **LD** command I get "*can not find*" message. Looks like it does not recognize "C". Otherwise I run program aster linking with "C" and asm. I get no error but I also do not get "C" functions.

[image]My output is:

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: The C library isn't available to you so printf isn't available unless you write it.. You will have to make your own. I recommend using a cross compiler and not a native GCC Windows compiler as that can invite unwanted problems that may make kernel development very difficult.

Comment: Your inline assembly has problems as well as it clobbers registers without telling the compiler. Your bootloader assumes segment registers are set to 0 but that may work in an emulator but on real hardware you may have issues.

Comment: One very serious problem about the actual code in the inline assembly is that it uses BIOS interrupts. You can't use those in protected mode. The processor will fault if that code is reached and likely cause the machine to reset with a triple fault.

Comment: The whole thing is very doubtful. Where did you take this tutorial? You should stop following it at the least.

Comment: First, @Michael Petch thank you for advices. That was helpful. comment 1.) I do not use linux but sources mostly based on linux. So I thought I may use a tutorial to do it but that was a very bad idea. Do you think that I can get better results with linux version ?, with statement "The C library isn't available to you" you mean I do not have the clib ? GCC should have it but somehow that has no lib. 2) you mean I did not disable interrupts ? 3)thank you for warning, I got that.

Comment: There are quirks with WINPE executables that can cause problems for OS Development. You don't need to use Linux, but using a good cross compiler would work. You would have better luck though using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) as it is much easier to build a cross compiler for it. When you build with `-ffreestanding` the C library is no longer available so when you write an OS you have to provide your own code that did the work of the C library. The C library in Windows (or Linux) works on top of an actual OS, but you don't have an OS when you do OS Dev.. you are writing one.

Comment: In your _C_ code you do `"int $0x10;"` in the inline assembly. None of the BIOS routines (software interrupts) are available to you in protected mode. So like writing a C library you also have to write code that writes directly to the screen yourself.

Comment: I think I should use UEFI, instead of bothering my time with this huh ? Intel doc page says I have many options instead of writing it.

Answer (score 0):

After I searched many documents, I have found that making a bootloader is very hard, not-hard at the same time. Yes, writing everything from stratch is impossible for me. Comments were correct, that may work in emulator but will cause many problems in real hardware. I can not deal with this. In the end, I found that intel had EFI. Whis is now UEFI. Still, I do not claim to know anything. But at least I learnt many things after searching. First, moving from windows to linux is easy in mind but hard to do for real. It is not possible to change your habits. First I searched for linux version of UEFI. There were many version problems. Then I looked for WIN version. Hopefully I found vs2019 compatible version of uefi environment. Project had no source in "gnu-efi" and thrown error when built. I searched the "gnu-efi-3.0.12" based on the info and downloaded it. I put the files inside of the main folder to "gnu-efi". Then, back to vs2019. Built it and build was successful. I ran it at debug mode aa64 platform. I got a windows message that that will download qemu once. That downloaded itself and I got qemu page with proper messages like:

```
Print(L"\n%H*** UEFI:HI I AM GOMI ***%N\n\n");
Print(L"%EPRESS ANY KEY AND EXIT.%N\n");
```

I also checked debug folder and found ".efi" files. I am not sure if I make a real bootable USB device and put compiled files that will work.

However, since thats efi I think that should boot.

**Source pages that I found useful**

A good site for uefi: *https://wiki.osdev.org/*

vs2019 compatible project: *https://github.com/pbatard/uefi-simple*

RESULT:
[image]